# Laravel storing PHP function code

Tags: php, laravel

Im using laravel for a website im making and I have a little account creation panel where I want to use JQuery AJAX to check if a username has been taken, however the JQuery.post function sends data to a PHP file , is there any way of sending a value to a controller / function to check for the username instead? I want to do this so I dont have to create a new php file everytime.

**EDIT**


Just wanted to clarify what I want to do: JQuery script sends a POST value to a CONTROLLER/FUNCTION and then the FUNCTION returns a value back which is displayed below the input , this is all done without refreshing the page and is all instant.

Comment: As far as the PHP code is concerned, the AJAX request will look the same as a normal GET or POST request, so it should be possible to configure it the same way you'd route a normal URL.

Comment: And how exactly would you make JavaScript method, which runs on browser, invoke a PHP (laravel) controller that resides on the server if not via invoking a URI in the first place? Do you know the differences between client side and server side?

Answer (score 2):

This is probably the most basic example for the server-side (Laravel) part:

```
// routes.php
Route::get('check-username/{username}', function($username) { // match a specific route
    $validator = Validator::make(
        array('username' => $username), // pass in the input we're validating
        array('username' => 'unique:users') // define a rule - should be unique in the users table
    );

    return Response::json( array(
        'exists' =>  $validator->fails(),
    ) );        
});
```

Then you can simply send a [GET request](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) to `/check-username/joe` and will receive a JSON object where the `exists` key indicates whether it's taken or not.

You can abstract the route into a controller easily if you want - this is just a basic example.

Answer (score -1):

```
Route::post('usernamecheck', function(){
$username = INPUT::get('username');
$checkUsername = DB::table('users')->where('username', '=', $username)->count();

if($countUsername == 0){
    //The number of rows with the username is 0, so you send back to the javascript using //echo and die() statements
    echo 'Username is Available';
    die();
}else{
   //The number of rows with the username is 0, so you send back to the javascript using echo and //die() statements
    echo 'Username is Taken';
    die();
}});
```

Dont Forget to put a

```
die();
```

after each

```
echo;
```

line when sending back to jQuery page so it stops the script from processing any further.

HTML:

```
<form action="script_to_send_form_to" method="POST">
    <input type="text" id="username_field" onkeyup(return(checkUsername()))>
    <span id="username_check_result"></span>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function(){
          var username = document.getElementById('username_field').value;

          var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
          var url = "usernamecheck";
          var params = "username="+username;
          http.open("POST", url, true);

         //Send the proper header information along with the request
         http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
         http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
         http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

         http.onreadystatechange = function() {
             //send the message you receive from php script to the username check result span
             document.getElementById('username_check_result').innerHTML = http.responseText;
        }
        http.send(params);  //this will send parameters to usernamecheck in the Route
    }
</script>
```

You can copy and paste the code straight into your project now
You should try to paste the javascript part at the end of the page, if its on the same page with the HTML. You can also include any other part of the form and if u want to run the same kind of validation on the, just follow the same concept above and specify a different Route for each one in your routes.php script.

Good Luck
Babs.... :)

Comment: Is there any way of doing this live? As in using keyup with JQuery and then sending the form value to the script above then sending back the response.

Comment: You shouldn't kill (use die() or exit()) Laravel, otherwise the App::after() doesn't get called and the shutdown process doesn't happen which could cause your app to stop working properly. jQuery seamlessly works with Json so you can leverage Laravel's `Response::json()` methods http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/responses#special-responses

Comment: I have edited my answer above to suite your needs, now including the javascript part and html...